# webpack output dropping dependencies

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, serverless-framework, webdriver-io

I have a node project using serverless + webpack. I am having an issue where my lambda cannot find a node dependency even though it is specified in my package.json and it is getting loaded locally.

serverless.yml

```
service: test-lambda
package:
  individually: true
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-scheduler
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs10.x
    timeout: 300
    region: us-east-2
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js 
    includeModules: true
functions:
  run:
    handler: src/handler.runTest
    events:
      - http:
          path: runTest
          method: post
      - http:
          path: runTest/{project}/{name}
          method: post
```

package.json dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.1.1",
    "chromedriver": "^75.1.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.16.2",
    "serverless": "^1.48.4",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.8.0",
    "serverless-offline-scheduler": "^0.3.8",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.38.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.503.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@wdio/logger": "^5.11.0",
    "find-node-modules": "^2.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "tmp": "^0.1.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.11.10",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.11.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/reporter": "^5.11.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.11.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^3.1.0",
    "wdio-json-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "wdio-reporter": "^5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "wdio-timeline-reporter": "^5.0.10",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.12",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "prom-client": "^11.5.3",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

In my local node_modules folder, I see these wdio dependency folders as expected, see image below:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4528753/62386889-c0cfc900-b51e-11e9-9130-75e86cced74a.png

However, when I run `serverless package` which subsequently executes the webpack, then inspect the zip file produced, I see the node_modules folder is missing those key dependencies "wdio-*", see image below:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4528753/62386982-012f4700-b51f-11e9-9efa-cb61000a424e.png

Where is everything else? I see no output from webpack indicating it ignored these...

Finally, here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false,
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false,
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: 'test/**/*',
        to: '.'
      },
      {
        from: 'reporters/**/*',
        to: '.'
      },
      {
        from: 'wdio.conf.js',
        to: 'wdio.conf.js'
      },
    ]),
  ],
};
```

What am I missing here?
I am positive it has nothing to do with serverless/serverless-webpack, as I can run webpack by itself to inspect it's output and I see the modules missing.

### Additional Data

- ***Serverless-Webpack Version you're using***: 5.3.1
- ***Webpack version you're using***: 4.38.0
- ***Serverless Framework Version you're using***: 1.48.4
- ***Node.js version***: 10.16.0
- ***NPM version***: 6.9.0
- ***Operating System***: mac osx
- ***Stack Trace (if available)***: ...

Answer (score 3):

How are you importing the missing packages in your Lambda function?
You might need to [force include](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#forced-inclusion) them in your `serverless.yml`

```
# serverless.yml
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      forceInclude:
        - module1
        - module2
```